# jQuery: How do I get an inline style (background-color) from one element and add it to a different element?

Tags: jquery, background-color

The background-color is being added to the element dynamically. What I need is to grab the inline style that's applied and add that same rgb background-color and add it to another element with rgba.

```
<section id="story" style="background-color: rgb(122, 86, 126)">
 <div class="row main text-center medium-text-left">
  <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-5 columns photo">
    <img src="assets/imgs/home/girl-closeup.jpg" alt="Close up of Natalia's face" data-adaptive-background>
    <h2 [Need background-color, but rgba applied here]>Natalia Summers - Age: 9<br>Fight: Lymphoma</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-7 columns story">
    <h3>Natalia's Story</h3>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
var color = $("#story").css("background-color");
color = color.replace(')', ', 0.75)').replace('rgb', 'rgba');
$("#story h2").css("background-color",color);})
```

replace the 0.75 with whatever 'a' value you need.

Comment: however, because you are putting the same color on top, you wont actually see anything different.

Comment: This works perfect, except for on caveat. The background color for #story is being loaded dynamically as well. So there isn't a color there to get before this ^ script loads. This is loading first so there's no color to grab. What do I need to do to force this script to load after the background script loads.

For some further context. The first script that set's background is an adaptive background plugin that's loading the color based on the colors in an image in that container (in this case #story img is setting the background color for #story).

Comment: Many ways to do that. One idea. Make this a named function and call it at the end of the function that sets the background color. Or if you don't want to get into the plugin code you can add a set timeout to this function so it will wait a few seconds before firing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#story").css("background-color") can be used to get the color value.
```

You can use the code above to retrieve the color and use something like this to assign the color:

```
var color = $("#story").css("background-color");
$("selector").css("background-color",color);

// This should assign the color to the h2 element
$("#story").find("h2").css("background-color",color);
```